# Ruby: new array from one value in an array of objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

Forgive me if this has already been asked, I couldn't find it.

I have an array of objects, like:

```
[<#Folder id:1, name:'Foo', display_order: 1>,
<#Folder id:1, name:'Bar', display_order: 2>,
<#Folder id:1, name:'Baz', display_order: 3>]
```

I'd like to convert that array into an array just of the names, like:

```
['Foo','Bar','Baz']
```

and, while I'm at it it would be nice if I could use the same technique down the road to create an array from two of the parameters, ie name and display order would look like:

```
[['Foo',1],['Bar',2],['Baz',3]]
```

What's the best 'Ruby Way' to do this kind of thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the many answers! htanata's was the most complete.

Comment: +1 for your first step into functional programming.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about these?

```
# ['Foo','Bar','Baz']
array = folders.map { |f| f.name }
# This does the same, but only works on Rails or Ruby 1.8.7 and above.
array = folders.map(&:name)

# [['Foo',1],['Bar',2],['Baz',3]]
array = folders.map { |f| [f.name, f.display_order] }
```

Comment: To clarify, `f.map(&:name)` works without Rails in 1.8.7 and (at least) 1.9.2.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
a.collect {|f| f.name}
```

Comment: or use `a.collect!` if you really want to replace it. For the second question: Hust extend it a bit to `a.collect{|f| [f.name, f.display_order]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
array.map { |a| [a.name, a.display_order] }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `['Foo','Bar','Baz']` , you can do: `array.map(&:name)`

For the second one you could use `array.map {|a| [a.id, a.name] }`