# Getting a list of names from a list of objects

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array "Groups". Each of the group-objects has an attribute name. I want to get a list of all those names, and maybe also the corresponding IDs, to put in a drop-down select in rails.

Is there a very ruby way to do this?

In PHP, I'd do something like:

```
group_names = Array.new
Groups.each do |group|
  group_names << group.name
end
```

But this doesn't feel very rubyish at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195943/ruby-new-array-from-one-value-in-an-array-of-objects/5196020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is essentially this:

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

For example:

```
<%= f.select("type_id", Object.all.collect {|o| [ o.name, o.id ] }) %>
```

[Checkout more options here](http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Select-helper-methods-in-Ruby-on-Rails).

Comment: Wohoo! Thanks. (comments must be 15 chars in length)

Answer (score 3):

Use `map`

```
group_names = groups.map{|group| group.name}
```

or the short form

```
group_names = groups.map(&:name)
```